# Filterizr gallery images overlap when using LazySizes

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I'm trying to get **Filterizr** (a jQuery plugin bit like isotope) to work with **LazySizes** ('SEO friendly lazy loader for images'). As I understand it the images are loaded into the DOM after the LazySizes has been initialised so it gets image heights wrong and they all overlap each other. I’d like to keep the images responsive I can’t give them a fixed height as on different browser widths they then begin to overlap again, and it would mean having loads of media queries for different widths (it gets very messy). So I need some method where Filterizr can maybe load after the images or gain a correct height somehow?

I have a CodePen demo here http://codepen.io/heavymessing/pen/dWvNaM

HTML:

```
      <div class="row" style="width:300px;float:left;">

        <ul class="simplefilter">
          <li class="active" data-filter="all">All</li>
          <li data-filter="1">Cityscape</li>
          <li data-filter="2">Landscape</li>
          <li data-filter="3">Industrial</li>
          <li data-filter="4">Daylight</li>
          <li data-filter="5">Nightscape</li>
        </ul>
      </div>


       <div class="row" style="width:100%; display: block; float: left;">

        <div class="filtr-container">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="1, 5" data-sort="Busy streets">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/400x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">Busy Streets</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="2, 5" data-sort="Luminous night">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/410x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">Luminous night</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="1, 4" data-sort="City wonders">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/420x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">city wonders</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="3" data-sort="In production">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/430x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">in production</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="3, 4" data-sort="Industrial site">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/440x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">industrial site</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="2, 4" data-sort="Peaceful lake">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/450x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">peaceful lake</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="1, 5" data-sort="City lights">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/460x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">city lights</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="2, 4" data-sort="Dreamhouse">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/470x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">dreamhouse</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="3" data-sort="Restless machines">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/480x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">restless machines</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="1, 5" data-sort="Busy streets">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/490x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">Busy Streets</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="2, 5" data-sort="Luminous night">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/500x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">Luminous night</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="1, 4" data-sort="City wonders">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/510x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">city wonders</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="3" data-sort="In production">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/520x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">in production</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="3, 4" data-sort="Industrial site">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/530x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">industrial site</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="2, 4" data-sort="Peaceful lake">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/540x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">peaceful lake</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="1, 5" data-sort="City lights">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/550x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">city lights</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="2, 4" data-sort="Dreamhouse">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/560x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">dreamhouse</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="3" data-sort="Restless machines">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/570x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">restless machines</span>
          </div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="1, 5" data-sort="Busy streets">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/580x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">Busy Streets</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="2, 5" data-sort="Luminous night">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/590x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">Luminous night</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="1, 4" data-sort="City wonders">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/600x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">city wonders</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="3" data-sort="In production">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/610x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">in production</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="3, 4" data-sort="Industrial site">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/620x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">industrial site</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="2, 4" data-sort="Peaceful lake">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/630x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">peaceful lake</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="1, 5" data-sort="City lights">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/640x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">city lights</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="2, 4" data-sort="Dreamhouse">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/650x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">dreamhouse</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="3" data-sort="Restless machines">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/660x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">restless machines</span>
          </div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="1, 5" data-sort="Busy streets">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/670x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">Busy Streets</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="2, 5" data-sort="Luminous night">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/680x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">Luminous night</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="1, 4" data-sort="City wonders">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/690x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">city wonders</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="3" data-sort="In production">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/700x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">in production</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="3, 4" data-sort="Industrial site">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/710x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">industrial site</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="2, 4" data-sort="Peaceful lake">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/720x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">peaceful lake</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="1, 5" data-sort="City lights">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/730x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">city lights</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="2, 4" data-sort="Dreamhouse">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/740x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">dreamhouse</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="3" data-sort="Restless machines">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/750x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">restless machines</span>
          </div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="1, 5" data-sort="Busy streets">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/760x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">Busy Streets</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="2, 5" data-sort="Luminous night">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/770x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">Luminous night</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="1, 4" data-sort="City wonders">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/780x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">city wonders</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="3" data-sort="In production">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/790x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">in production</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item lazyload" data-expand="-20" data-category="3, 4" data-sort="Industrial site">
            <img data-src="http://pipsum.com/800x400.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload" alt="sample image">
            <span class="item-desc">industrial site</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    body {
        margin-top: 1rem;
    }
    .filtr-item {
        padding: 1rem;
    }
    .item-desc {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1rem;
        z-index: 1;
        bottom: 1rem;
        left: 1rem;
        right: 1rem;
    }

    /* Filter controls */

    .simplefilter {
      dispaly: block;
      float: left;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .simplefilter li, .multifilter li, .sortandshuffle li {
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 1rem 2rem;
    }
    .simplefilter li {
        background-color: #585858;
    }
    .simplefilter li.active {
        background-color: #212121;
    }
    .multifilter li {
        background-color: #4b9eff;
    }
    .multifilter li.active {
        background-color: #2265b4;
    }

    /* Shuffle and sort controls */
    select {
        padding: 1rem 1rem;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .sortandshuffle .shuffle-btn {
        background-color: #dec800;
    }
    .sortandshuffle .sort-btn {
        background-color: #de0000;
    }
    .sortandshuffle .sort-btn.active {
        background-color: #9d0000;
    }

    /* Search control */
    .search-row {
        margin-left: 2.5rem;
    }
    .filtr-search {
        padding: 0.5rem;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }


    .lazyload,
    .lazyloading {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .lazyloaded {
      opacity: 1;
      transition: opacity 300ms;
    }
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
      $(".filtr-container").imagesLoaded(function() {
        //images loaded plugin

        var filterizd = jQuery(".filtr-container").filterizr({
          animationDuration: 0.5, //in seconds
          delay: 150,
          delayMode: "progressive",
          easing: "ease-out",
          filter: "all",
          filterOutCss: {
            //Filtering out animation

            transform: "scale(0.5)"
          },
          filterInCss: {
            //Filtering in animation
            transform: "scale(1)"
          },
          layout: "sameWidth",
          selector: ".filtr-container",
          setupControls: true
        });
      });
    });
```

above the body tag:

```
<script>
      window.lazySizesConfig = window.lazySizesConfig || {};
      window.lazySizesConfig.expand = 0;
</script>
```

I'm also using the ImagesLoaded plugin but seems to nothing? (Also I know the images in pen are different heights but even if they where the same I'd still get the same result).

Thanks,